# RMarkdown beamer & Table of content

Tags: r, r-markdown, tableofcontents

I am trying to create my first set of slides using RMarkdown beamer.

What I have so far:

```yaml
---
title: title
author: author
date: date
output: beamer_presentation: default
ioslides_presentation: default
linkcolor: blue
---
    
## Plan for today
    
text
        
## Outline
    
text
    
## Day 1
    
text
    
## Day 2
    
text
    
## Day 3
    
text
    
## Day 4
    
text
    
## Day 5
    
text
```

I have seen presentations with the Table of Contents at the top in the header and when the presenter changes to a new slide with a different section, it highlights the section in the header where the presenter is. What's the piece of code I need in order to do this? Ideally I want in the Table of Contents 'Plan for today' and 'Outline' under **Introduction**, and then **Day 1**, **Day2**, etc. up to **Conclusion**.

I also want to:

1. add a picture to the header at the top right corner
2. add page number in the footer at the bottom right corner like 3/14 (only after the title page)

Any thoughts? Many thanks in advance.

A picture of what I am trying to do:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a TOC in the header, it's best to choose among [predefined themes](https://hartwork.org/beamer-theme-matrix/) which support this, e.g., *Szeged*, and then specify it in the YAML with `theme: Szeged`.

To get the desired outline you need to use the right combination of first-level (starting with `#`) and second-level (starting with `##`) section headers, see below. I also set `slide_level: 3`.

Adding a logo to the top right, page numbers to the footer and a custom title slide requires some LaTeX code that needs to be inserted in the template used to compile the final PDF output. You can do this by including code in a separate .tex file using the `includes` option in the YAML header of the .Rmd file. It should look like this:

**presentation.Rmd**

```
---
output:
  beamer_presentation:
    theme: Szeged
    slide_level: 3
    includes:
      in_header: header.tex
---

# Introduction

## Plan for today
text

## Outline
text

# Day 1

text

# Day 2

and so on ...

# Conclusion

your conclusion
```

**header.tex**

```latex
% add custom title slide
\setbeamertemplate{title page}{
  \inserttitle\\[0.5ex] 
  \insertauthor\\[0.5ex] 
  \insertdate
  \pagenumbering{gobble}
  \thispagestyle{plain}
}
% remove title slides at beginning of sections
\AtBeginSection{}
\AtBeginSubsection{}
% add page counter to the footer
\setbeamertemplate{footline}[frame number]
\setbeamertemplate{frametitle}{}
% add logo
\usepackage{textpos}
\addtobeamertemplate{frametitle}{}{%
\begin{textblock*}{100mm}(0.9\textwidth,0.5cm)
 \includegraphics[height=0.5cm,width=1cm]{logo}
\end{textblock*}}
```

The logo is a .PNG file from [here](https://www.iconsdb.com/white-icons/search-3-icon.html). For your image to be displayed nicely you'll likely need to make some adjustments to positioning and size. Note that *header.tex* and *logo.png* need to be in the same directory as *presentation.Rmd*.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot for this. I have many sections e.g. Introduction, Day 1, Day 2, ... Day 6, Conclusion. By using this theme, it is difficult to have the TOC in the header because it goes in the vertical direction. I actually saw it once in a presentation going in the horizontal direction, but could not find that theme. I guess you haven't seen it, but just asking to confirm. Thanks!

Comment: I went through all Beamer themes and 'Szeged' could work. How could I edit the header so that it only shows the first section and not the 2nd one below (when looking at the Szeged theme)? It is too much information. The presentation I have seen with the sections of the TOC in the header must have been edited because it is not listed in the available themes.

Comment: I would also like to remove the info that goes automatically in the footer using this theme, and include page number such as 13/30. Not sure if you know how to edit a theme? Thanks!

Comment: I'm not sure I follow. Setting `theme: Szeged` in the YAML header works fine for me. Now of course the position (and the color) of the logo are not optimal but this is easily adjusted for by altering parameters in *header.tex*. 
If you don't want a frame title (?) add `\setbeamertemplate{frametitle}{}` to *header.tex*.

Comment: The style of the theme: Szeged includes 2 sections in the header with a total of 3 blue lines. But I only need the top section (2 lines) with the TOC. The section below is blank - is it possible to remove it? One last question, second-level section headers are not showing on the slides, how to include them? Thanks!

Comment: I see. If specified, subsection titles are displayed between the second and the third blue line (`slide_level: 3`). Unfortunately, it is not that easy to remove this. Since this is not really related to rmarkdown, I suggest you post the question at [tex.stackexchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: It is working ok now. Just one last point, how to remove the header and page number from slide 1?

Comment: I've edited my answer accordingly. It now also shows how to include a title page without page number.